# what does cmp do in assembly language

Tags: assembly, cmp

I was just wondering what this does. As of now I just think that it compares %rsp with %eax but Im not really sure what the 0x10 there for

```
cmp    0x10(%rsp),%eax
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is AT&T syntax for comparing the DWORD at memory location `(rsp+10h)` to the value in `eax`. The Intel syntax equivalent is:

```
cmp eax,[rsp+10h]
```

If the syntax difference is what is confusing you, check out [this site](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) which gives a good basic comparison between the two.

BTW, comparing the *value* of `rsp` with `eax` would be (AT&T):

```
cmp %rsp,%eax
```

or (Intel):

```
cmp eax,rsp
```